# AS3 UML Tools other than Crocus Modeller

Tags: actionscript-3

I have been using Crocus Modeller a lot this past year, and it's been great. It's the first UML tool I've used, and so I don't know how it compares, but it seems to work very well. However, today I just got a MacBook Pro (first Mac) and while Crocus Modeller is an air application, it does not work properly (it doesn't even work properly in a Windows 8 vm using Parallels - which seems quite strange). I'm searching for a new tool. I haven't found any other AS3 UML tools, but I thought I'd ask to see if there is anything else people are using.

In case anyone is wondering, the problem with Crocus Modeller on the MacBook is that certain keys on the keyboard do not seem to register. Specifically, the S, D, F, G, H, L, C, and V letters do not register (they do register when holding down the shift key - but that is no workaround). This happens when running the air application natively in OSX as well as in the Windows 8 virtual machine using Parallels.

**Summary of primary question:** what are some good UML tools that can export AS3 code stubs?

**Bonus question:** I'm assuming there's no fix for the keyboard issue in Crocus Modeller, but if there is that would be an ideal solution to this problem.

Comment: As the [first question of the FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) says, "What tool should I use for X"-questions are off topic on GameDev. I recommend asking on discussion forums or perhaps [our chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Maybe they only register when holding shift because caps lock is on?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try UML4AS: http://www.uml4as.com

UML4AS is an Eclipse Plugin. It allows you to work with diagrams, to generate code, reverse engineer and the whole round-trip scenario.

UML4AS works on both Windows and Mac. You can give it a try. Take a look at its "bigger brother", Flower Dev Center ( http://learn-discuss.flower-platform.com/flower_dev_center/ ), that allows you to model ActionScript projects, using the web browser.

Best regards,
Cristian

Comment: Cristian, we typically try to expand our answers a bit more. Just providing a link is not very useful if the link were to go dead. Additionally, this site is aiming to be a repository of expert knowledge. Solely linking to an outside site doesn't add to that goal.

Comment: I am sorry about this; I have updated my answer.

Comment: Oops, I didn't notice before that you were promoting your own product. That's typically frowned upon here. Especially when you don't explicitly call it out in your answer. This answer sounds very much like an advertisement.

Comment: This was also recommended to me by a developer friend today. Regardless of it being his product, it looks like it could answer my question perfectly.